# T-SQL to merge data from different rows under different columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert, group

I have a table with data for each column distributed in different rows. Need help with getting all the data into a single row.

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jacob | Joseph | Ben | NULL | NULL |
| Jacob | Joseph | NULL | NULL | Reuben |
| Jacob | Joseph | NULL | Judah | NULL |

I want to populate all the data in one row like below:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jacob | Joseph | Ben | Judah | Reuben |

I am new to T-SQL and unable to get to where I want. Please help.

I initially had an Excel sheet with the data scattered across the columns in an odd way. After a lot of reformatting I got it to this point and imported into SQL Server to fix it through T-SQL. I tried a few things with insert into table selecting from the table but unable to arrange the data in a single row.

Comment: `select Max( [Column A] ) as [Column A], ... from MyUnnamedTable;`?

Comment: You need a [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregate and GROUP BY to solve this

```
SELECT 
    ColumnA,
    ColumnB,
    MAX(ColumnC) AS ColumnC,
    MAX(ColumnD) AS ColumnD,
    MAX(ColumnE) AS ColumnE
FROM 
    YourTable
GROUP BY 
    ColumnA, ColumnB;
```

Here is the sample [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UrfutnYH)